# Switching superuser permissions?

Tags: rooting, root-access, superuser, supersu

I used Kingoroot to root my Micromax Canvas A116 yesterday. And Kingoroot installed its own superuser app as a rooting procedure.

The problem is kingoroot's superuser is paid and displays ads and auto install apps if you don't buy it. I tried downloading Supersu but it gives an error "SU binaries occupied". How can I change superuser permissions from Kingoroot to Supersu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all DONT root with Kingoroot, Kingroot, or with any other one click rooting crap. They install ad binaries that run with root permissions mine IMEIs and things like that.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2516942

> Remember the little discussion we had going in a thread here regarding vRoot, and i joked about vRoot was mining IMEIs? Well, apparently it's true. We have only ourselves to blame. I'm already rooted so i'll unlock my bootloader and install recovery. That way i don't need to root again if i screw something up. You "should" do the same if you're already rooted and don't care about losing Gracenote and X-Reality. Remember to backup your TA folder.
>   What does this mean? What are they able to do with our IMEI's (if they have them)? I'm not sure, and i won't speculate.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2515851&page=3

> ...
>   What XDA is concerned with is the fact that your devices Serial number and IMEI numbers are collected during the root process. This is something which is not necessary at all in order to achieve root. They also use free servers in China in order to minimize cost to themselves.
>   That is the concern. The reason you have seen back and forth on the subject is that it takes time for developers to reverse engineer the process to see exactly what it does.
>   So XDA at this time has taken a position that links to the Kingo or vRoot methods will not be posted on XDA. You are free to use Google and search it out and use any method you want. You aware of the risks just like any other mod you do your device.
>   Kingo has said they are correcting this and will be coming out with an app which will be self sustained and connection to their servers will not be necessary. They say it will be 2.0
>   Until such happens we will not be allowing the links, but you can discuss it all you want.
>   To be accusing the Kingo developers of doing underhanded things is just wrong and total made up speculation. XDA has to take the communities safety as priority #1.
>   Just look at this way would you take a screen shot of your devices status screen posting all your IMEI and personal information on a public forum on a site of developers and hackers?
>   It's always better to error on the side of safety.
>   EFM
>   Have a great day!

But to answer your question SuperSU can only manage the SU requests if it self has SuperSU, so you need to

1. Replace it with SuperSU VERSION 2.79 (the version is important)
2. re-root with CF-auto-root over ODIN or .zip file

Comment: I downloaded superuser pro and unistalled superuser using it and then unistalled superuser pro. Now i downloaded Supersu and its working fine. Is there a need to re root?